# how to get filename from url without extension?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have file url => https://development.com:3000/api/file/92
I want to get file name form that url
Ex: 92.pdf or 92.png depend on file type ot that url

Comment: It's impossible to determine the type of a file from *only* its path. You will need to read (part of) the file to inspect its contents and then use, say, `package:mime` to deduce the file type.  See the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

If the file name is always the last part of your url, maybe you can try something like `url.split('/').last`. This code essentially "splits" your url based on the `/` character, and then take the last component.